# "Outside the house boys waited with the patient for the doctor. "

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

1. Outside the house boys waited with the patient for the doctor.
2. Boys waited with the patient for the doctor  outside the house.
3. Boys waited for the doctor with the patient outside the house.

Which sentence is grammatically wrong? please explain.

Comment: None of them is grammatically wrong, but I think they all read awkwardly because of the repetition of three-word phrases. You could vary it by saying something like 'the boys were staying with the patient as he waited for the doctor'

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that any are not grammatical, but they mean slightly different things.

> Outside the house, some boys waited with the patient for the doctor

does not necessarily mean that the patient was outside; the sentence is ambiguous. Outside seems to apply with special emphasis on the boys. It could be clarified with

> Some boys and the patient waited outside the house for the doctor.

All waited outside the house. Or if that was not meant

> Some boys waited outside the house for the doctor while the patient waited inside.

Only the boys waited outside.

Your second sentence

> Some boys waited with the patient for the doctor outside the house

is less ambiguous because it does not emphasize the boys, but it is technically unclear whether outside applies to the boys, the patient, the doctor or some combination of those parties.

The sentence

> Some boys waited for the doctor with the patient outside the house

is equally ambiguous and also is awkward. It seems to imply initially that the boys needed a doctor.

Thus, none of the sentences is completely free of ambiguity.

If what is meant is that the boys and the patient were outside, the second sentence is the best of the lot. If what is meant is that only the boys were outside, the first sentence is the best of the lot. But neither sentence is completely clear.